# Anonymous functions with no input parameters

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I'm trying to figure out C#'s syntax for anonymous functions, and something isn't making sense to me.  Why is this valid

```
 Func<string, string> f = x => { return "Hello, world!"; };
```

but this isn't?

```
 Func<string> g = { return "Hello, world!"; };
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The second still requires the lambda syntax:

```
Func<string> g = () => { return "Hello, world!"; };
```

In the first, you're effectively writing:

```
Func<string, string> f = (x) => { return "Hello, world!"; };
```

But C# will let you leave off the `()` when defining a lambda if there is only a single argument, letting you write `x =>` instead.  When there are no arguments, you must include the `()`.

This is specified in section 7.15 of the C# language specification:

> In an anonymous function with a single, implicitly typed parameter, the parentheses may be omitted from the parameter list. In other words, an anonymous function of the form
>
> ( param ) => expr
>
> can be abbreviated to
>
> param => expr

Answer (score -2):

You need to know the function definition:

> Encapsulates a method that has **one parameter** and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

References:

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Comment: `Func<string>` (which is what his second example is using) is a function that takes no parameters and returns a string.